# Using a FFmpeg trim filter to trim a video, while preserving its audio (with filter_complex)

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I reached a part where I can cut the video with

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -filter_complex
'[0:v] trim=start=5:end=10,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [cut]' -map [cut]  output.mp4
```

And it successfully trims the video. However, it completely removes the audio. I'm trying to chain a couple of different filters, so I'd like to keep the similar syntax, just to somehow preserve the audio.

Comment: Do you intend to also filter the audio eventually?

Comment: nope, i'm combining the video with a couple of still images, but i want to preserve the video's original audio (from the trimmed part of course, so audio from 5th to 10th seconds in the example above)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple method for audio is to declare input twice and use `-ss` & `-t`, and then map this stream:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -ss 5 -t 5 -i test.mp4 -filter_complex 
'[0:v] trim=start=5:end=10,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [cut]' -map [cut] -map 1:a -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Answer (score 20):

You can also use the `atrim` filter to trim the audio and the `asetpts` filter to modify the audio timestamp:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -filter_complex \
'[0:v] trim=start=5:end=10, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [v0]; \
 [0:a]atrim=start=5:end=10,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS [a0]'\
 -map [v0] -map [a0]  output.mp4
```

Comment: I need to add that if you're running this command on Win and you're using this as a reference, don't use a single quote around the filter complex ['] use a double quote ["] or else you'll be yelling at your screen trying to understand why it's not working. Also for windows users don't use backslash [\\] as shown here. It's a way in linux to make long commands look cleaner.

Comment: The last `;` in the filter description shouldn't be there, cause FFmpeg thinks that there will be another filter: `[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7fcc3ec2aa80] No such filter: ''`