# How can I cut a video to a certain length and add an intro video to it using ffmpeg-python?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-python

How can I cut a video to a certain length and add an intro video to it using ffmpeg-python?

I am doing this:

```
intro = ffmpeg.input(intro)
mainvid = ffmpeg.input(mainvid)

v1 = intro.video
a1 = intro.audio
v2 = mainvid.video
a2 = mainvid.audio

joined = ffmpeg.concat(v1, a1, v2, a2, v=1, a=1).node
v3 = joined[0]
a3 = joined[1]

(
    ffmpeg
    .output(
        v3,
        a3,
        'out.mkv',
        vcodec='libx265', )
    .run()
)
```

But I don’t know how to cut *mainvid to a certain length like 10 minutes before joining. I know ss will help, but I don’t know how to use it for only *mainvid*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it using:

```
        intro = ffmpeg.input(intro)
        mainvid = ffmpeg.input(mainvid, ss='00:00:00', t='00:10:00') 

        v1 = intro.video
        a1 = intro.audio
        v2 = mainvid.video
        a2 = mainvid.audio

        joined = ffmpeg.concat(v1, a1, v2, a2, v=1, a=1).node
        v3 = joined[0]
        a3 = joined[1]

        (
            ffmpeg
            .output(
                v3,
                a3,
                'out.mkv', 
                vcodec='libx265', )
            .run()
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `trim` and `atrim` filters for trimming the video and the audio.
The suggested solution is based on the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56109487/4926757).

- FFmpeg supports [3 types](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) of concatenation: "Concat demuxer", "Concat protocol" and "Concat filter".
  The method `ffmpeg.concat` applies [Concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat).
  Since "Concat filter" is used, a practical  solution is trimming the video and audio by "chaining" `trim` and `atrim` filters.
- `setpts` and `asetpts` filters are required for fixing the timestamps.

---

Replace `v2 = mainvid.video` and `a2 = mainvid.audio` with:

```
v2 = mainvid.video.filter('trim', start=0, end=600).filter('setpts', 'PTS-STARTPTS')
a2 = mainvid.audio.filter('atrim', start=0, end=600).filter('asetpts', 'PTS-STARTPTS')
```

Comment: I managed to do it using "  mainvid = ffmpeg.input(mainvid, ss='00:00:00', t='00:10:00')   "

Is it the right way to do?

Comment: Also is 600 is in seconds?

Comment: Yes 600 is in seconds. Your solution is simpler, you can post it as an answer to your own question.

Comment: Ok will do, and thanks your answers helped me a lot!! HAVE A GREAT DAY!